# ios - confused as to where in the plist I need to set the bundle id

Tags: ios, plist

I know I have done this before, but I am looking all over the xcode files and can not find the darn plist file :) Could someone please remind me how to get to it.

Thank you! And sorry for such a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on your project in Xcode, and then select the Info tab.

That is your application .plist  and the Bundle identifier can be set right in there.

Comment: thank you :) I will accept in 5 min when StackOverflow allow me :)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, I would like to add here so such type of problem will never be faced again.

Whenever, it seems that you're not able to seek file from directory structure at shown by XCode on his left pannel, in that case it's better just to use the search option which is present just below the directory structure just for an instance if you want to check out your plist file as in this case, you just need to write 'plist' at search and XCode intelligence work it's own and will depict that particular file.And, also in the case if you've confusion in your file name, just type there some keywords of that filename and it'll depict all that files which have those keywords.(Remember that XCode is depicting the files and then use search option, which is present below.)